# Change display property and id attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have 2 sections:

```
<section class="notes animate" id="need" style="background:#fff; height:900px; padding-top:70px;">
 <!--stuff --->
</section>

<section class="focus" id="need" style="display:none;">
 <!--stuff --->
</section>
```

I want to display the second section when window is lowered to width less than 1043px. And hide the first section by `display:none`

Update:
How can I remove id attribute of first section, when width is less than 1043?

Comment: Use media queries.

Comment: `id` attributes have to be unique

Comment: @AndFisher It doesn't matter for me here. I want to remove id attribute of first section and keep id attr of second section as it is, when width is less than 1043.

Comment: If you could specify in your question why you need to remove the id attribute, then perhaps you can write some JavaScript to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You should use CSS media queries. You can read more about it here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

For example:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1043px) {
    section.focus {
      display: block;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you cannot use same ID for more than one div. So change the id of one div.
And to hide the second div and show the first div:

Use CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1043px) {
  .focus {
    display: block;
  }
  .notes {
    display: none;
  }
 }
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning unique IDs, the OP would also need to remove inline style for `display`. Also they'd need to invert the display properties outside of the media query

Comment: Yeah i am appreciating your comment @AndFisher :)

Answer (score 0):

In response to your requirement for removing the ID attribute, try the following JavaScript. It can only do it once however, and if you are interested in performance you should consider investigating debounce/throttle for the resize handler. (http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce/examples/debounce/)

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    if($(window).width() < 1043) {
        $('.notes').removeAttr('id');
        $(window).off('resize');
    }
});
```

However, the media queries answers are the correct approach to show/hide based on screen width.